# How to select all distinct filename extensions from table of filenames?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of ~20k filenames.  How do I select a list of the distinct extensions?  A filename extension can be considered the case insensitive string after the last `.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use substring_index:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(column_containing_file_names,'.',-1) FROM table
```

-1 means it will start searching for the '.' from the right side.

Answer (score 1):

there is A very cool and powerful capability in MySQL and other databases is the ability to incorporate regular expression syntax when selecting data example

SELECT something FROM table WHERE column REGEXP 'regexp'

see this http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/

so you can write pattern to select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @bnvdarklord is right but it would include file names which does not have extensions as well in result set, so if you want only extension patterns use below query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring_index(column_containing_file_names,'.',-1) FROM table where column_containing_file_names like '%.%';
```